# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute

Tags: python, sockets

Trying to program a socket in python but keep getting attribute errors every time I try to use the socket module.  The attributes should be there.  They are rather basic things. I have at this point just copy and pasted tutorial code and still it gives me error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\micheal\workspace\GCNSocket\socket\GCNSocket.py", line 18, in <module>
    except socket.error, msg:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'error'
```

and my code is

```
import time
import socket
import sys

host_ip="209.208.78.170"
port=8099                   
if __name__ == "__main__":
   currentTime=time.time() #current time (time)
   lastTime=time.time() #records last time of last received packet (time)

   try:
       mySocket=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM) # create socket
   except socket.error, msg:
      print ('Failed to create socket. Error code: ' + str(msg[0]) + ' , Error message : ' + msg[1])
      sys.exit()

  print("Starting Connection")
  if(mySocket.connect((host_ip,port))): #connect
       print("Connected to 209.208.78.170  port 8099")
  else:
       print("Unable to Connect")
```

If I remove the try block and just create the socket, I get same error with 'socket' instead of 'error'

Comment: Look at your traceback and ask yourself what happens when you create a package called `socket` in your code. Your traceback shows you ran your code from `GCNSocket\socket\GCNSocket.py`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `socket` as a package name. It cause import of your package `socket` instead of standard library module `socket`.

Rename it so it does not collide with standard library module name.

Comment: It is a *package* called `socket`; you can see it in the traceback: `GCNSocket\socket\GCNSocket.py`.